# Showing a hidden div with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have the following code right...

```
<div id="viewFrame">
  <iframe src="preview.php" name="previewFrame" width="100%" height="100%" style="display:none;"></iframe>
</div>
```

And also:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function previewFrame(){
  document.preview.submit();
  var preview = document.getElementById('viewFrame');
  preview.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

...Oh, and I also have

```
<form name="preview" action="preview.php" method="post" target="previewframe">
  Some more code here...
</form>
```

It will hide the div but when I try to submit the form, it won't show the iframe. Anyone know what is wrong?

EDIT: Ok, here is the full code for the page:

```
<head>
<title>EasyPage</title>
<?
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function insertlink(){
    var url = prompt("URL:");
    var text = prompt("Text:");
    var link = "<a href=" + url + ">" + text + "</a>";
    var linksbox = document.getElementById("links");
    linksbox.value = linksbox.value + link;
  }

  function insertlink2(){
    var url = prompt("URL:");
    var text = prompt("Text:");
    var link = "<a href=" + url + ">" + text + "</a>";
    var contentbox = document.getElementById("content");
    contentbox.value = contentbox.value + link;
  }

  function insertimage(){
    var url = prompt("Image URL:");
    var image = "<img src=" + url + " />";
    var contentbox = document.getElementById("content");
    contentbox.value = contentbox.value + image;
  }

  function insertlineopen(){
    var line = "<p>";
    var contentbox = document.getElementById("content");
    contentbox.value = contentbox.value + line;
  }

  function insertlineclose(){
    var line = "</p>";
    var contentbox = document.getElementById("content");
    contentbox.value = contentbox.value + line;
  }

  function previewFrame(){
    document.preview.submit();
    var preview = document.getElementById('previewFrame');
    preview.style.display = 'block';
  }
</script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:black">

  <div style="font-size:72px; text-align:center; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Times New Roman; color:lime; background-color:black;">
    <b>EasyPage</b>
  </div>

<div style="font-size:24px; text-align:right; font-family:Sans Serif; color:; background-color:orange;">
  <a href="/index.php">Home</a> <a href="/create.php">Create</a> <a href="/logout.php">Logout</a>
</div>

<div style="font-size:18; text-align:center; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Times New Roman; color:yellow; background-color:black;">
  <form name="create" action="process.php" method="post" target="_blank">
  <form name="preview" action="preview.php" method="post" target="previewFrame">
    <table style="color:yellow; margin:auto;">
      <tr><td colspan="3"><hr /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Title: </td><td><input type="text" name="title" /> </td><td><i>This text shows in the title bar</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Background Colour: </td><td><input type="text" name="back" /> </td><td><i>The background colour of the entire page.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="3"><hr /></td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;">Heading:</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Text: </td><td><input type="text" name="heading" /> </td><td><i>The heading at the top of the page.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Size: </td><td><input type="text" name="hsize" /> </td><td><i>The size of the heading.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Align: </td><td><input type="radio" name="halign" value="left" /> Left     <input type="radio" name="halign" value="center" /> Center <input type="radio" name="halign" value="right" /> Right </td><td><i>The alignment of the heading.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Font Family: </td><td><input type="text" name="hfont" /> </td><td><i>The font style for the heading.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Colour: </td><td><input type="text" name="hcolor" /> </td><td><i>The colour of the heading.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Background Colour: </td><td><input type="text" name="hback" /> </td><td><i>The background colour of the heading.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="3"><hr /></td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;">Link Bar:</td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="3" style="text-align:right; color:white; cursor:pointer;"><a onclick="insertlink()"><u>Insert Link</u></a></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Links: </td><td><input type="text" name="links" id="links" /> </td><td><i>The links that show below the heading.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Size: </td><td><input type="text" name="lsize" /> </td><td><i>The size of the links.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Align: </td><td><input type="radio" name="lalign" value="left" /> Left <input type="radio" name="lalign" value="center" /> Center <input type="radio" name="lalign" value="right" /> Right </td><td><i>The alignment of the links.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Font Family: </td><td><input type="text" name="lfont" /> </td><td><i>The font style for the links.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Background Colour: </td><td><input type="text" name="lback" /> </td><td><i>The background colour of the link bar.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="3"><hr /></td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;">Content:</td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="3" style="text-align:right; color:white; cursor:pointer;"><a onclick="insertlineopen()"><u>Open New Line</u></a> <a onclick="insertlineclose()"><u>Close Line</u></a> <a onclick="insertlink2()"><u>Insert Link</u></a> <a onclick="insertimage()">    <u>Insert Image</u></a></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Content: </td><td><input type="text" name="content" id="content" /> </td><td><i>The page content.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Size: </td><td><input type="text" name="csize" /> </td><td><i>The size of the text content.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Align: </td><td><input type="radio" name="calign" value="left" /> Left <input type="radio" name="calign" value="center" /> Center <input type="radio" name="calign" value="right" /> Right </td><td><i>The alignment of the content.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Font Family: </td><td><input type="text" name="cfont" /> </td><td><i>The font style for the text content.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Colour: </td><td><input type="text" name="ccolor" /> </td><td><i>The colour of the text content.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Background Colour: </td><td><input type="text" name="cback" /> </td><td><i>The background colour of the content.</i></td></tr></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="3"><hr /></td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;">Footer:</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Text: </td><td><input type="text" name="footer" /> </td><td><i>The footer text.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Size: </td><td><input type="text" name="fsize" /> </td><td><i>The size of the footer.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Align: </td><td><input type="radio" name="falign" value="left" /> Left <input type="radio" name="falign" value="center" /> Center <input type="radio" name="falign" value="right" /> Right </td><td><i>The alignment of the footer.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Font Family: </td><td><input type="text" name="ffont" /> </td><td><i>The font style for the text content.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Colour: </td><td><input type="text" name="fcolor" /> </td><td><i>The colour of the footer.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Background Colour: </td><td><input type="text" name="fback" /> </td><td><i>The background colour of the footer.</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="3"><hr /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Filename: </td><td><input type="text" style="text-align:right;" value="index" name="filename" />.html </td><td><i>The name of the file. (For security reasons, file extensions cannot be changed.)</i></td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;"><a onclick="previewFrame()" style="color:white; cursor:pointer;"><u>Preview</u></a> <input type="submit" value="Create" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    <div id="viewFrame">
      <iframe src="preview.php" id="previewFrame" name="previewFrame" width="100%" height="100%" style="display:none;"></iframe>
    </div>
  </form>
  </form>
</div>

  Copyright 2012, Nathan Piercy. All rights reserved.
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: the iframe has `style="display: none;"`...?

Comment: Oh, right... I didn't even notice. :P
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Going off of Hristo's comment, try adding id="previewFrame" to the iframe itself, and then update getElementById to call previewFrame.

e.g.

```
<div id="viewFrame">
     <iframe src="preview.php" id="previewFrame" name="previewFrame" width="100%" height="100%" style="display:none;"></iframe>
</div>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function previewFrame(){
    document.preview.submit();
    var preview = document.getElementById('previewFrame');
    preview.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

Or just use a JavaScript framework to more easily select and show elements.

Comment: Still doesn't work... I will add the full code for the page in the first post.

Comment: If I run your exact code, Firebug is saying that "document.preview" is undefined (I guess I should have seen that before). If I comment out that line, the iframe is displayed correctly.

Comment: So you'll need a selector on the form to submit it, because document doesn't understand that ".preview" is supposed to be the form.

Comment: Weird... Thanks for helping anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `style="display: none;"` from the `<iframe>`...?